# Entity Framework Core 5: store Guid as a blob (not string) in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, blob, guid

As I understand, it is quite good to store *guid* as a *blob* because it is only 20 bytes, which in *string* representation will take much more and the comparison will take longer. However, I couldn't get **EFC** (on **NET 5.0** with **EF6** installed) to store the *guid* in binary form (without crutches like storing an array of bytes).

`guidBinary` isn't allowed. Error occurs: `Connection string keyword 'guidbinary' is not supported`. Environment variable does not work.